# Log JSON-RPC calls using web3.js

Tags: web3js, json-rpc

In ethers.js you can log JSON-RPC calls like this:

```
  ethers.provider.on("debug", (info) => {
    if (info.request) {
      console.log("Request:", info.request);
    }
    if (info.response) {
      console.log("Response:", info.response);
    }
  }
```

Is there any similar code for web3.js?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Alchemy [here](https://composer.alchemy.com/) to create scripts which link to your desired chain and allow you to debug **all sorts** of RPC calls, from logs, via web3's `eth_getLogs`, to token datas via alchemy's `alchemy_getTokenMetadata`.